# In Fluent ui 9 react component popover is not showing up

Tags: fluent, fluent-ui, fluentui-react

I am using

```
"@fluentui/react-components": "^9.7.1",
```

error: Modalizer i9 must have either aria-label or aria-labelledby

I am getting this warning and I have checked there is no error but when I click on the trigger, It shows this warning in the console and popover dosent open

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it's because Fluent UI v9 does not support React v18 yet, see [this](https://github.com/microsoft/fluentui/issues/24423) GitHub issue, which causes some issues with React's StrictMode.

You can solve the issue by disabling Strict Mode.